# Lucia-auth session for non logged in client

Tags: typescript, authentication

I've just recently migrated to using Lucia auth to handle my app's authentication. After reading through their documentation and creating an implementation in my app, I am under the impression that they do not support creating and tracking sessions for clients that do not have a logged in user, is this really the case?